# Solve the recurrence $A(n) = 2A(n/2) + O(1)$.

Tags: algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science

> Solve the recurrence $$A(n) = 2A(n/2) + O(1)\,.$$

I have done the following:

I have guessed the result to be $\Omega(n)$

Hypothesis: For $k < n$, $$A(k) \geq c k\,.$$

Substitution: $$A(n) \geq 2c(n/2) + O(1) = A(n) \geq 2c(n/2) + d\,.$$

Simplify: $$A(n) \geq cn + d\,.$$

What to do now?

Comment: Did you mean "For all $m<n$, $A(n)\geq mn$"?  If so, the claim $A(n)=\Omega(n)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Then, $A(n)\geq n(n-1)=\Omega(n^2)$, so why do you expect $A(n)=\Omega(n)$, when $A(n)$ grows at least as fast as $n^2$?

Comment: Did you read carefully the answer below before "accepting" it?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question after you've received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(n)=2\,A\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+c_n$.  If $a\leq c_n\leq b$ for all $n$, then by induction (or via telescopic sum), one can show that
$$2^k\,A(1)+(2^k-1)a\leq A(2^k) \leq 2^k\,A(1)+(2^k-1)b\,.$$
This means 
$$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{A(2^k)}{2^k}\geq A(1)+a\text{ and }\limsup_{k\to\infty}\,\frac{A(2^k)}{2^k}\leq A(1)+b\,.$$

It is not true that $A(n)=\Omega(n)$ in all cases, though.  In the unlucky case, where $a=b=-A(1)$, we get $A(2^k)=A(1)$ for all $k$.  Thus, $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\,\left|\frac{A(n)}{n}\right|=0\,.$$

Comment: But $A(n)=A\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+c_n$ with $a\leq c_n\leq b$ is **not** the hypothesis.

Comment: It is.  You have $A(n)=2\,A(n/2)+O(1)$, so $c_n:=A(n)-2\,A(n/2)$ form a bounded sequence.

Comment: Sorry but I read $A(n)=2A(n/2)+$remaining term, not $A(n)=A(n/2)+$remaining term.

Comment: A typo on my part, but the idea remains the same.  I edited the comment and the answer.